# Confused converting timestamp to local time in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've written a query that groups metrics into 5 minute buckets and counts the number of occurences in each bucket.

This is the query:

```
select count(*)                                                           as amnt,
       case when firmness < 90 then 'indicative' else 'executable' end    as metric,
       to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from _received) / 300)) * 300) as time
from feedintra
where _received >= now()::date
  and firmness is not null
  and firmness between 0 and 90
group by firmness, time
order by time;
```

The results look like so:

```
| amnt | metric | time |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 1584| indicative| 2022-11-16 21:25:00.000000 +00:00|
| 36290 | executable| 2022-11-16 21:25:00.000000 +00:00|
| 1250| indicative| 2022-11-16 21:25:00.000000 +00:00|
| 53074| executable| 2022-11-16 21:25:00.000000 +00:00|
```

What I want to do is convert the time so that it's in UTC. When I try to do this, 11 hours is *added* to time, presumably because PostgreSQL thinks the time is already in UTC.

```
select count(*)                                                           as amnt,
       case when firmness < 90 then 'indicative' else 'executable' end    as metric,
       to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from _received) / 300)) * 300) at time zone 'Australia/Sydney' at time zone 'UTC' as time
from feedintra
where _received >= now()::date
  and firmness is not null
  and firmness between 0 and 90
group by firmness, time
order by time;
```

The data now looks like this:

```
| amnt | metric | time |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 1584| indicative| 2022-11-17 08:25:00.000000 +00:00|
| 36290 | executable| 2022-11-17 08:25:00.000000 +00:00|
| 1250| indicative| 2022-11-17 08:30:00.000000 +00:00|
| 53074| executable| 2022-11-17 08:30:00.000000 +00:00|
```

I want it to be:

```
| amnt | metric | time |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 1584| indicative| 2022-11-16 10:25:00.000000 +00:00|
| 36290 | executable| 2022-11-16 10:25:00.000000 +00:00|
| 1250| indicative| 2022-11-16 10:30:00.000000 +00:00|
| 53074| executable| 2022-11-16 10:30:00.000000 +00:00|
```

How can I make PostgreSQL treat the time column as 'Australia/Sydney' time and then convert this to UTC?

Comment: How about `'epoch' from _received at time zone 'Australia/Sydney'`

Comment: The answer depends on the data type of `_received`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Good point. If `_received` happens to be a `timestamptz`, my initial answer needs a `::timestamp` to cheat it.

Comment: Fixed it, plus added a `date_bin()` that OP seems to be emulating through the extract+divide+floor+multiply+cast operation.

Comment: I think it would be good to clarify the rationale behind this whole operation: it's not uncommon that people want to "convert" between time zones without knowing all time zone aware date/times are stored the same, uniform timezone implied, and "timezone layer" is there just to handle offsets in read/write interpretation. There could be a scenario where some data was fed with the wrong time zone info, so it has to be found and corrected, but this doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Yes, that question needs clarification. I have voted to close

Comment: @Zegarek The problem is that the application that is writing these records is saving local timestamps in a column that is implicitly UTC - the rationale is to workaround this problem so that tools that only understand UTC timestamps (e.g. Grafana) can use the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the `at time zone 'Australia/Sydney'` to where you interpret `_received` and make sure your timestamp in `_received` isn't already aware of the time zone (being of type `timestamptz`/`timestamp with time zone`):

```sql
select count(*)                                                        as amnt,
       case when firmness < 90 then 'indicative' else 'executable' end as metric,
       date_bin('5 minutes',_received::timestamp,'today') at time zone 'Australia/Sydney' as time
from feedintra
where _received >= now()::date
  and firmness is not null
  and firmness between 0 and 90
group by firmness, time
order by time;
-- amnt |   metric   |          time
--------+------------+------------------------
--    1 | indicative | 2022-11-16 10:25:00+00
--    1 | executable | 2022-11-16 10:25:00+00
--    1 | indicative | 2022-11-16 10:30:00+00
--    1 | executable | 2022-11-16 10:30:00+00
--(4 rows)
```

I added a built-in [date_bin()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN) function for improved readability and ease of use. It does exactly the same thing, plus it lets you align your time "buckets" arbitrarily, not just round/truncate to whole units.

Before:

```sql
table feedintra;--raw test data
-- firmness |      _received
------------+---------------------
--       89 | 2022-11-16 21:25:00
--       90 | 2022-11-16 21:25:00
--        0 | 2022-11-16 21:30:00
--       90 | 2022-11-16 21:30:00
--(4 rows)

select count(*)                                                           as amnt,
       case when firmness < 90 then 'indicative' else 'executable' end    as metric,
       to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from _received) / 300)) * 300) at time zone 'Australia/Sydney' at time zone 'UTC' as time
from feedintra
where _received >= now()::date
  and firmness is not null
  and firmness between 0 and 90
group by firmness, time
order by time;
-- amnt |   metric   |        time
--------+------------+---------------------
--    1 | indicative | 2022-11-17 08:25:00
--    1 | executable | 2022-11-17 08:25:00
--    1 | indicative | 2022-11-17 08:30:00
--    1 | executable | 2022-11-17 08:30:00
--(4 rows)
```

What-could-go-wrong cheatsheet for text `'2022-11-16 21:25:00.000000 +00:00'::text`:

```sql
         output         |                               interpretation
------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2022-11-16 21:25:00+00 | ::timestamp
 2022-11-16 10:25:00+00 | ::timestamp at time zone 'Australia/Sydney'
 2022-11-16 10:25:00+00 | ::timestamp at time zone 'Australia/Sydney' at time zone 'UTC'
 2022-11-16 21:25:00+00 | ::timestamp at time zone 'UTC'
 2022-11-16 21:25:00+00 | ::timestamptz
 2022-11-17 08:25:00+00 | ::timestamptz at time zone 'Australia/Sydney'
 2022-11-17 08:25:00+00 | ::timestamptz at time zone 'Australia/Sydney' at time zone 'UTC'
 2022-11-16 21:25:00+00 | ::timestamptz at time zone 'UTC'
 2022-11-16 21:25:00+00 | ::timestamptz::timestamp
 2022-11-16 10:25:00+00 | ::timestamptz::timestamp at time zone 'Australia/Sydney'
 2022-11-16 10:25:00+00 | ::timestamptz::timestamp at time zone 'Australia/Sydney' at time zone 'UTC'
 2022-11-16 21:25:00+00 | ::timestamptz::timestamp at time zone 'UTC'
```